# Meteor doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: meteor, windows-10

I downloaded the Meteor's official Download from here: [Meteor 1.2.1](https://www.meteor.com/install)
and the installer is just `1.2mb`

Now, after running it: Nothing happens. No permission. Nothing. This page is shown:

[image: THis happens in 0.5s.]

And then when I hit `Skip this step`, this is shown:

[image: And it doesn't work.]

Even after restarting, there is no `.meteor` folder in AppData\Local directory, and Meteor command is still not recognised.

Also, I think, how can a `1.2mb`install something like Meteor which is like `53mb` when installed via curl on OSX or Linux.

Are the Meteor fooling windows? I dont know why the installer doesn't work. The point is: How can it?

Comment: Well that .meteor folder most likely will be created once you start the program for the first time. A 1.2MB installer can definitely install a 53MB software because installers can download things. Ever install Java? not sure what command you are trying but windows terminals is not the same as it is on mac or linux. However, the website does say it works natively with Windows (http://win.meteor.com/).

Comment: But when meteor command is not recognised, I am not sure how the rest of the program will get downloaded.

Comment: exactly , organization like `Meteor` is not fooling around people. I'm using Meteor in my windows 10 machine. If meteor command is not recognized, then check your environment variable.

Comment: I said there is no `.meteor` folder. The environment variable will have to have a path to a location that exists to work.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded file is installer not setup.
First install the meteor in your machine.
Then set it in environment variable.